# Why am I able to still write to a file marked 400

Tags: files, permissions

```
root@user123:~# touch 1.pwd
root@user123:~# chmod 400 1.pwd
root@user123:~# echo "abc" > 1.pwd

root@user123:~# vi 1.pwd

root@user123:~# ls -lart
total 3344
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     148 Aug 17  2015 .profile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    3106 Apr  9  2018 .bashrc
drwx------  3 root root    4096 Dec 13 13:35 .dbus
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Dec 13 13:35 .local
drwx------  7 root root    4096 Feb 21 10:47 .config
-rw-------  1 root root   39013 Mar  4 11:57 .bash_history
drwx------ 12 root root    4096 Mar  4 12:45 .
-r--------  1 root root       4 Mar  4 12:45 1.pwd

root@user123:~# echo "no change" >> 1.pwd
root@user123:~# cat 1.pwd
abc
no change
```

The permission management successfully alters the file to read-only. Then why would writes to the file still succeed. How can I avoid this situation.

Comment: Don't use the machine as root.

Comment: With the first command you rewrite the file so your chmod has no effect. Use `>>` for the first write attempt and you'll see the correct output.

Comment: @eblock that's not right (see the OP's `ls` output later in their question). It's simply that permissions can be overridden as root.

Comment: @eblock The `>` redirection would _not_ unlink the file and recreate it.  Editing the file with `vi` might do that, but `>` would just truncate it. This is possible to do for this user since he's root.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I will block root and sudo root access to the machine

Comment: That makes much more sense, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard permissions can be overridden by root.

Simple solution: don't use root unless you really need to do so. That way you're far less likely to delete or break something vital to the system

Comment: Thank you. I will create users who would run the job. Any non-root user gets bash: conf.bkp: Permission denied. Many Thanks !!